# apply validation on mailing address on contact object but given Error: Syntax error. Extra ','

Tags: validation

```
ISBLANK ( MailingCity),
ISBLANK ( MailingCountry ),
ISBLANK ( MailingPostalCode ),
ISBLANK ( MailingState ),
ISBLANK ( MailingStreet )
```

if any field like city , country , postal code, state, street is blank popup error message **complete address required along with all details of city,country,postal code, state etc.
but it give Error: Syntax error. Extra **','**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a validation rule

that will fire if any one of the field is blank.

Use OR operate to check all the field `ISBLANK ()` will return true if field is blank.

```
OR(ISBLANK ( MailingCity),
ISBLANK ( MailingCountry ),
ISBLANK ( MailingPostalCode ),
ISBLANK ( MailingState ),
ISBLANK ( MailingStreet ))
```